# detect object with color

Tags: kinect, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I am using the tabletop object detector to determine some object on point cloud database.
http://www.ros.org/wiki/tabletop_object_detector

I was wondering  if I would able to somehow also extract color information about the objects. I want to know that  can I use color information or RGB image by tabletop library? If not ,does anybody know of a tool that does anything similar???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/155211/detect-object-with-color/) by [ghazaleh](https://answers.ros.org/users/11236/ghazaleh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,
This is what you need - Voxelized Shape and Color Histograms (VOSCH)

---

Originally posted by [adreno](https://answers.ros.org/users/4576/adreno/) with karma: 253 on 2014-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ghazaleh](https://answers.ros.org/users/11236/ghazaleh/) on 2014-04-20**:
Thank's Adreno I think it's good. but I got problem in VOSCH installation. I follow this link http://wiki.ros.org/vosch ,but when I run :
rosrun vosch example_vosch `rospack find vosch`/data/sample_cone_green.pcd
I got the Error that Couldn't find executable named example_vosch below /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/mapping/vosch. what is the problem?

**Comment by [adreno](https://answers.ros.org/users/4576/adreno/) on 2014-04-26**:
Did you rosmake ? You have to build the package to generate the executables...